# Bash and Expect: Is there a way to ignore or remove ANSI control sequences from Expect buffer?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I'm using Expect to connect to my server over a (virtual) serial port. (HP iLo, to be specific)

When booting from a Linux OS ISO image, you eventually get to the '**boot:**' prompt. When my server reaches that prompt, I would like to enter my own custom boot options and press enter. Easy, right?

This is how the boot prompt looks when you're watching my Expect script execute (looks normal):

```
boot:
```

However, I have not been able to match '**boot:**'. Looking at the Expect Buffer in my logfile, this is what is being captured for that line:

```
ESC\[25;01HbbESC\[25;01HESC\[25;02HooESC\[25;02HESC\[25;03HooESC\[25;03HESC\[25;04HttESC\[25;04HESC\[25;05H::ESC\[25;05HESC\[25;06H  ESC\[25;06HESC\[25;07H"
```

I think all those control sequences are screwing up my match. If you look closely '**boot:**' is actually in there, but it's surrounded by what I believe are ANSI control sequences.

In fact, the logfile is absolutely full of ANSI control characters.

Relevant pieces of the Expect script I've been playing around with:

```
bash #] expect -d -c '
    .....
    # SSH to the Virtual Serial Port Management server
    spawn ssh user@1.2.3.4
    .....
    # Access the Virtual Serial Port for the server being booted
    send "vsp\r"
    .....
    # After rebooting the server, when the boot: prompt appears, enter boot options
    expect {
        "boot:" {send $bootOptions \r\n"}
        timeout {send_user "Never found boot prompt\n"; send_user "$expect_out(buffer)"; exit 1}
    }
    .....
    exit'
```

Any ideas about what the best way to handle those control characters would be? I've tried exporting TERM=dumb and TERM=vt1000 on the machine I'm running the script on. Didn't make much of a difference.

Comment: `TERM=` on the machine you are running the script on would (potentially) affect the behavior of the *script itself*, but doesn't get propagated across the ssh connection.  Unfortunately, brief poking around on HP's website gives me the impression that iLo insists on emitting control sequences as if it were talking to a VT320, no matter what; so you've pretty much gotta filter them somehow in Expect.  And I have no earthly idea how to do that.

Comment: not sure if this will help, but this RegExp appears to be matching: `ESC\\\[25;[0-9][0-9]` and there is a routing called `regsub -all` which ive found comes in handy while expect'ing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but you could create a wrapper for ssh and exec that instead of ssh and then have

```
ssh <host> | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b
```

perhaps take out the col -b which filters newlines if you don't need that.